# Mapping array of hashes to JS objects or maps

Tags: javascript, mongodb, hash

I want to make a function in JS which accepts an array of hash as an argument and then maps the values of the hash to an object(JS) or map(of JS).

The idea is to use the values stored in the hash to assign to either an object or a map (both of Javascript). Then I will use the values from map or object to set them as "href" and "src" of  and  tag respectively. so in short I want to dynamically assign the values of "href" and "src" from the values which are coming from array of hash. and this array of hash is coming from mongodb.

Kindly help and sorry that i don't have any code to show for this.

```js
<script>
var url = "http://www.google.com";
var iamge = "1.jpg";
function myFunc()
{
  document.getElementById("imAg").src = iamge;
  document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = url;
 } 
myFunc();
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a id="myAnchor" href=" "><img id="imAg" src=" "></a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my html code and myFunc() needs to have the code which will initialize "iamge" and "url". (In this code though both are statically initialized). i want both to be initialized dynamically using the array of hash coming from mongodb.

Comment: The question in its current form is too broad for stackoverflow. It's also not clear, when and how you want to change `src` and `href`. Is the table available on page load? Will it be loaded from a backend server via ajax?

Comment: @Danmoreng in addition, I'm confused about the terminology used - OP mentions a hash, and object, and a map. These are three concepts for sure but in JS you have an *object* which some call hash. Some will also call it a map but with ES6 there is a [different Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). So in this case these three seemingly distinct items refer to two or maybe one concept.